# unity change transform object through script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I have a script which detects how far away an object is via its transform and displays it to the player, I want the target object to change once it gets destroyed so the objective marker points to a different object. here is my code so far

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class DistanceToPickup : MonoBehaviour {

    // Reference to checkpoint position
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform checkpoint;

    // Reference to UI text that shows the distance value
    [SerializeField]
    private Text distanceText;
    GameObject exit;
    // Calculated distance value
    private float distance;


    private void Start()
    {
        exit = GameObject.Find("Door_01");

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {

        // Calculate distance value between character and checkpoint
        distance = (checkpoint.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;

        // Display distance value via UI text
        // distance.ToString("F1") shows value with 1 digit after period
        // so 12.234 will be shown as 12.2 for example
        // distance.ToString("F2") will show 12.23 in this case
        distanceText.text = "Pickup: " + distance.ToString("F1") + " meters";

        if (Pickup.isDestroyed == true)
        {
            //point transform checkpoint to new object
            checkpoint = exit.transform;
            distanceText.text = "Exit: " + distance.ToString("F1") + " meters";
        }
    }

}
```

I have found the game object that I want to point the marker too and changed the checkpoint marker to point to the exits transform but it isn't changing the distance text, I can't see anything wrong with the code. any help will be much appreciated

Pickup class

```
public class Pickup : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject m_ExplosionPrefab;
    private ParticleSystem m_ExplosionParticles;
    private int pickupCounter = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text PickupText;
    public static bool isDestroyed;


    private void Update()
    {
        PickupText.text = "Pickups: " + pickupCounter + " /1";
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Instantiate the explosion prefab and get a reference to the particle system on it.
        m_ExplosionParticles = Instantiate(m_ExplosionPrefab).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

        // Disable the prefab so it can be activated when it's required.
        m_ExplosionParticles.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            pickupCounter++;
            isDestroyed = true;
            // Move the instantiated explosion prefab to the tank's position and turn it on.
            m_ExplosionParticles.transform.position = transform.position;
            m_ExplosionParticles.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            // Play the particle system of the tank exploding.
            m_ExplosionParticles.Play();

            PickupText.text = "Pickups: " + pickupCounter + " /1";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you check if `Pickup` is destroyed, but what is `Pickup`? i do not see it defined anywhere, also if the object is destroyed you should check if checkpoint is null right?

Comment: hi! is it checking the boolean isDestroyed in the Pickup class. the isDestroyed boolean is a public static variable so  I can access it from this class

Comment: If you destroy this.gameObject, you destroyed this.gameObject and destroyed stuff is, well, destroyed and cant do stuff anymore. You may want control the destruction by a different GameObject that actually lives on to tell the tale ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a workaround. The code wouldn't work because I was trying to access a variable in the Pickup script but the pickup script gets destroyed when `Destroy(this.gameObject);` is called.

To get around this I only destroyed parts of the component that I didn't need to use once the condition was met. I did this by writing `Destroy(this.gameObject.getComponent<whatever component you want to destroy on the object>());` i hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
    private void Update()
{

    // Calculate distance value between character and checkpoint
    distance = (checkpoint.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;

    // Display distance value via UI text
    // distance.ToString("F1") shows value with 1 digit after period
    // so 12.234 will be shown as 12.2 for example
    // distance.ToString("F2") will show 12.23 in this case
    distanceText.text = "Pickup: " + distance.ToString("F1") + " meters";

    if (Pickup.isDestroyed == true)
    {
        //point transform checkpoint to new object
        checkpoint = exit.transform;
        distanceText.text = "Exit: " + distance.ToString("F1") + " meters";
    }
}
```

to this:

```
    private void Update()
{
    if (Pickup.isDestroyed == true)
    {
        //point transform checkpoint to new object
        checkpoint = exit.transform;
        distanceText.text = "Exit: " + distance.ToString("F1") + " meters";
    }
    else
    {
        // Calculate distance value between character and checkpoint
        distance = (checkpoint.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;

        // Display distance value via UI text
        // distance.ToString("F1") shows value with 1 digit after period
        // so 12.234 will be shown as 12.2 for example
        // distance.ToString("F2") will show 12.23 in this case
        distanceText.text = "Pickup: " + distance.ToString("F1") + " meters";

   }
}
```

Comment: hello, I have tried that and it did not work. I believe I have figured out the problem. when I destroy the pickup once the player has hit it then it also destroys any reference to the variable so i cannot access it. I have tested this by checking the isDestroyed checkbox on and off during gameplay from the hierarchy view and doing that it works but once I hit the pickup object and it destroys it then it doesn't work